SD card detected but no /dev entry created
Relevant dmesg:
[980875.386648] mmc0: new SD card at address cde5
lsblk doesn't see it. /dev content does not change on insertion. The reader is integrated but sits on the USB bus.
Anything beyond here is beside the point and is best not read.

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x0129 RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
  bcdDevice           39.60
  iManufacturer           1 Generic
  iProduct                2 USB2.0-CRW
  iSerial                 3 20100201396000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 CARD READER
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 [unknown]
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 
      iInterface              5 Bulk-In, Bulk-Out, Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0003  1x 3 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 [unknown]
  bDeviceSubClass         0 [unknown]
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

So do I have the appropriate kernel module? It seems out of two neither is installed, unless modprobe rtsx_usb is the wrong command.
What am I doing wrong? In the off chance of "not much" and considering rtsx_usb doesn't seem to be available for my system, is compiling and installing  rts5139 likely to work?

Are usb_storage & uas modules both loaded?

@Bib thanks! Do You think the question is better off closed or should I just delete it?

Solved questions is by far not a SE thing, perhaps it should be deleted, perhaps left closed for someone landing from google on it.

Solved questions should be kept around and kept open, but the answer should be posted as an answer, and not embedded within the question. Please post a separate answer and [edit] the question.

As @Bib indicated, and as the docs explain: Dear Arch users, do always reboot after a kernel upgrade.
The docs say "packages will not be upgraded" but it's a lot more sinister than that. Modules are not loaded. Things stop working. Just reboot.
All Arch-specific. I believe debian-based systems lack this prob...eh sorry: this learning step.
